# Having issues working out minimum and maximum calculations within my forms on c#

Tags: c#, forms, class

I am creating a student module form with multiple functions. I am having issues reading the minimum and maximum values within the list box. I have been struggling for days and would greatly appreciate any form of help. Thanks in advance!

I have tried using different arrays, storing different values ect. I thought the issues within the code came from no 'mark' being stored. But i am certain that it is working and believe the issues lies within the line of code in 15.

```
public int MinMark()
        {
            int lowest = int.Parse(ModuleData.studentMark[0]);
            for (int index = 1; index < ModuleData.studentMark.Count;index++)
            {
                if (int.Parse(ModuleData.studentMark[index]) < lowest) 
                {
                    lowest = ModuleData.studentMark.ToString()[index];
                }
            }
            return lowest;
```

So far my code is just outputting the first index on from the list. i have explored all my lecture notes and have tried anything i can think of to get it working.

Comment: `lowest = ModuleData.studentMark.ToString()[index];` Well that can't be right.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can you point me in the right direction to where im going wrong? thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
lowest = ModuleData.studentMark.ToString()[index];
```

is incorrect and would give you the char value of a character in the string. What the above line is doing is taking the mark which is a string, converting it to a string again, and then selecting the character at index `index` from that string.

Instead you want the the string as an integer which can be achieved as below

```
lowest = int.Parse(ModuleData.studentMark[index]);
```

Comment: Hi ChubbyPanda! i somehow missed that i set the value to 1, i am fully aware that it should be set to 0 and have made a rookie mistake lol! thanks for the help i am very greatful!

Comment: I just realised that setting it to 1 works fine since you have already checked the initial element. (so you're fine to have it as 1, it actually makes it faster)

Comment: So am i better to set the value to 1 or just keep it at 0? thanks again!

Comment: 1 is the better option in this case only. In future projects this may be counted as an error.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for all your help greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: No problem, remember you can accept an answer by pressing the green ticks under the vote buttons and once you have enough reputation you can vote as well.

Comment: Just done it there sorry i wasn't aware that is how you did it thanks!

Comment: ChubbyPanda another task i have is to edit a mark within the list, I am trying to use a return value and get method. Can you shine any light on how i could go about doing this? i have not covered this in class but aim to get a head start before its due. Not sure if i am aloud to ask another question within a question, if that is the case i apologise!

Comment: You're not supposed to. Ask another question and give me the link here and I'll answer it right away for you.

Comment: Just curious as to why you prefer Jonathon's answer to mine?

Comment: I used both your explanations to help me with my program? what do you mean by this, i greatly appreciate your help! I also can't post another question for x amount of minutes. Is there any other way we can chat? thanks Panda!

Comment: As in, you're supposed to mark the one that helped you most, is the most sussinct, provides the best explanation, etc. I'm just trying to improve my answers :)

Comment: I apologise i wasn't aware i could only mark one answer, i tried to do both! Is there any other way to help with this problem, it wont let me post another question yet :(

Comment: What's the issue? Not enough reputation?

Comment: I am no allowed to post another question within 90minutes :(

Comment: Oh yeah. Sad times. I'm afraid you can't do much about that other than wait 90 minutes.

Comment: ChubbyPanda i have added a new question that we spoke about but in alot more detail, would you still be willing to help me please? Thanks again for all your advise! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533790/editing-record-from-a-list-box-on-a-separate-form

Answer (score 0):

```
lowest = ModuleData.studentMark.ToString()[index];
```

This line is almost certainly incorrect, as you're returning the string representation of your collection (likely something like `"System.String[]"` or `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]"`) and getting a character from the string by index and implictly converting that character to an integer. The line should likely be

```
lowest = int.Parse(ModuleData.studentMark[index]);
```

However, you can replace this method with a single LINQ query, like so:

```
public int MinMark() => ModuleDate.studentMark.Select(int.Parse).Min();
```

This will parse all the student marks to integers then select the smallest from the collection. If this is still only returning the first index, then the first index is likely the lowest value in your case, or the `ModuleDate.studentMark` field isn't being populated as you expect.

Comment: A beginner (as the OP seems to be) is unlikely to know what a LINQ query is let alone how to implement one. It's probably best this is left out.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, i expected that the line in question was wrong but i just wasn't sure on how to fix it. The line you suggested has now solved the problem for both my minimum and maximum calculations. In regards to the LINQ query unfortunately we are not allowed to use them in our assignment for some strange reason. Thanks so much for helping me with this issue it has been mind boggling me for quite some time now! really appreciate it!

Comment: @JackC Not being allowed to use LINQ in an entry course isn't too surprising since you're drilling the mechanics for control flow. Feel free to accept an answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I think we go into more detail with LINQ next year! yes Jonathon i will indeed new to this so wasn't entirely sure how to give positive feedback! can't thank you enough!