# editing record from a list box on a separate form

Tags: c#, forms, editing

In my program I allow the user to select a student record from the list box, when they hit the edit button a new form opens. This form displays the id and mark of the student they have selected. I am required to let the user edit that mark and update the list box. I am having trouble letting the user edit, and would appreciate any advise on this. 
(I am having trouble figuring out what to do when i have the users data inside the edit form) Thanks.

I am not allowed to use LINQ, so a solution or advice on how to do it without it would be greatly appreciated.

Main form when the edit button is clicked:

```
private void btnEditMark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] s_rec_arr;

    if (lstMarks.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please select a student");
    }
    else
    {
        ModuleData.s_rec = lstMarks.SelectedItem.ToString();
        s_rec_arr = ModuleData.s_rec.Split(':');
        ModuleData.s_id = s_rec_arr[0];
        ModuleData.s_mark = s_rec_arr[1];
        editMark myEditRecordForm = new editMark(); // Opens a form called editMark
        this.Hide(); // Hides the previous form
        myEditRecordForm.ShowDialog(); // Shows the form
    }
}
```

Edit form:

```
public partial class editMark : Form
{
    public editMark()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        txtStudentID.Focus();
    }


    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void editMark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStudentID.Text = ModuleData.s_id;
        txtMark.Text = ModuleData.s_mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm not really used to C#

Comment: No problem mate! Thanks anyways, seems like no one wants to help me with this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I only wrote the parts of codes which i changed.Other parts are same with yours.And as you wish no linq.**

[image]

**Firstly set Modifiers property of your listBox to Public for access it from another form.**

**Now here we go with codes.**

**Form1**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lstMarks.Items.Add("1:Bulutay"); //I don't know your list.This is my guess.
    lstMarks.Items.Add("2:Person2"); //
    lstMarks.Items.Add("3:Person3"); //
    lstMarks.Items.Add("4:Person4"); //
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] s_rec_arr;
    if (lstMarks.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please select a student");
    }
    else
    {
        ModuleData.s_rec = lstMarks.SelectedItem.ToString();
        s_rec_arr = lstMarks.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(':');
        ModuleData.s_id = s_rec_arr[0];
        ModuleData.s_mark = s_rec_arr[1];
        this.Hide(); //We hide our Main Form, it's still running at background and waiting to be shown again.We will use it.
        editMark myEditRecordForm = new editMark(); //Edit Form
        myEditRecordForm.Owner = this;  //We set New Edit Form's owner as this mainForm to access its lstMarks(listBox).
        myEditRecordForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Form editMark**

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = txtStudentID.Text + ":" + txtMark.Text;
    string[] parts = data.Split(':');

    Form1 mainForm = (Form1)this.Owner; //We get our hidden owner's REFERENCE to mainForm object.

    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.lstMarks.Items.Count; i++) //loops mainForm.lstMarks.Items.Count
    {
        string[] item = mainForm.lstMarks.Items[i].ToString().Split(':'); //We test all of items one by one.
        if (item[0] == ModuleData.s_id) //if listbox's current item's ID part equals to our static ModuleData.s_id
            mainForm.lstMarks.Items[i] = data;  //Set new data.
    }

    mainForm.Show(); //We show our old Main Form which we hided before.
    this.Close();
}
```

**Screenshots from project.**

[image]

**I selected Person3 and clicked to UPDATE button**

[image]

**Changed data**

[image]

**Clicked to SUBMIT button**

[image]

**Updated (New) data**